# Not able to Authenticate using OAuth2 for Twitter from Postman

Tags: twitter, oauth-2.0, postman

I am trying to send the Single Tweet GET request from Twitter API v2 collection. I used the OAuth2 Authorization Type.
When I click on Get New Access Token, after providing the Configuration Options I get the following window:

[image: Something went wrong]

But when I click on Back, I am logged in to my Twitter account.

Meanwhile, my Get New Access Token window is still waiting to receive a response:

[image: Waiting for authentication]

Has anybody encountered this before?

I've tried using Bearer Token instead and it works without a problem.

I also tried logging out and logging back in from the Twitter login but still did not authenticate successfully.

Answer (score 3):

For me, it's because I used `localhost` in my callback URL.

> Don’t use localhost as a callback URL
> Instead of using localhost, please use a custom host locally or http(s)://127.0.0.1

ref: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/apps/callback-urls

Answer (score 1):

My Problem is solved Now, This issue was caused Because I have not added the Callback URL in the postman that I have added in the Twitter developer account project.

And Second main reason for that because I did not add the accurate scopes tweet.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my callback URI (ie. `example.com`) didn't match exactly with the callback URI I provided (ie. `https://example.com`)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue up until I moved my app from "STANDALONE APPS" to a project. [See removing app from project warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeD1B.png). Make sure the app you are trying to use is in a project. The solution is to "Move this App into a Project so that it can access v2 endpoints and OAuth 2.0". [See solution suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bgPQ.png). If the app you are trying to use is not in a project but is a standalone app, it won't be able to access OAuth 2.0. **Standalone Apps will fail when trying to make requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints or use OAuth 2.0 unless you connect them to a Project.**

Ref: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview